# Lose CSharp.dll when moving from .Net 4.0 to .Net 3.5 - Kills Menu Buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I began a web application in .Net 4.0, and one of the advantages of this is that the web application is initially created with the beautiful horizontal Menu Bar.

[image]

I need to downgrade this to .Net 3.5, and when I do so, I lose the Microsoft.CSharp.dll reference, and this menu is converted to ugly standard Hyperlinks.  Is there a way in .Net 3.5 to retain this menu?

Per Jon's request:
This is from Site.Master.  It is autogenerated (though I copied the About button for placeholders).

```
    <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
        <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false"  Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="Community"/>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="Extras"/>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="Contact"/>
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
    </div>
```

Nothing in the code-behind.  It is empty.

CSS:

```
/* TAB MENU   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

div.hideSkiplink
{
    background-color:#3a4f63;
    width:100%;
}

div.menu
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #bfcbd6;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

ADDITIONAL INFO:
What is above is the .Net 3.5. The .Net 4.0 is identical to it in every respect. The only difference between the two projects (have them open side by side) is the CSharp reference has the !bang by it in the 3.5 project, because it is an invalid reference.

Deleting the reference has no positive effect.

Comment: It's not clear what relationship you believe there is between Microsoft.CSharp.dll (which is primarily used to implement `dynamic`, as far as I'm aware) and whatever menu change you're seeing. It also doesn't help that you haven't posted any of your code, which makes it hard to tell what's happening...

Comment: Jon,  I am not aware of any relationship between them.  I just know that I create a new Web Application (have not written a single line of code yet), and with the automatically generated code (?template?) I have this beautiful menu.  Since I know I can't use .net 4.0, I change the .net version in the project properties.  When I do so, the menu becomes standard hyperlinks, and the only thing I can see that has changed is that the CSharp reference is now invalid.  Could be just a coincidence.  I can certainly add the auto-generated code if you believe that would help.

Comment: Ideally, include a minimal example of each (the .NET 4.0 code and the .NET 3.5 code). Get rid of everything which is clearly not relevant (e.g. the text in the body).

Comment: What is above is the .Net 3.5.  The .Net 4.0 is identical to it in every respect.  The only difference between the two projects (have them open side by side) is the CSharp reference has the !bang by it because it is an invalid reference.

Comment: Please include this information in the *question* where it makes more sense. Bear in mind that you'll be pulling in different *versions* of the same DLLs...